# Do falling factorials form a Schauder basis for formal power series in some topology?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, topological-vector-spaces, formal-power-series

We usually talk about $F[[x]]$, the set of formal power series with coefficients in $F$, as a topological ring.  But we can also view it as a topological vector space over $F$ where $F$ is endowed with the discrete topology.  And viewed in this way, $\{x^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Schauder basis for $F[[x]]$.

Now in contrast, $\{(x)_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $(x)_n$ denotes the falling factorial, is not a Schauder basis for $F[[x]]$.  That’s because if $\Sigma_na_n(x)_n$ never converges in the standard topology on $F[[x]]$ if infinitely many of the $a_n$’s are nonzero.  But my question is, does there exist some alternate topology on $F[[x]]$ which makes $\{(x)_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a Schauder basis for $F[[x]]$ as a topological vector space over $F$ endowed with the discrete topology?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the monomials won't form a Schauder basis for $F[[x]]$ when equipped with the discrete topology. In order for a sequence to converge in the discrete topology, it must be eventually constant, and hence a series converging must in the discrete topology must contain only finitely many non-zero terms. This means, there'd be no way to form a power series that wasn't a polynomial as a convergent infinite sum of monomials.

Comment: @TheoBendit To be clear, we’re not endowing $F[[x]]$ with the discrete topology.  We’re endowing $F[[x]]$ with its standard topology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Topological_structure $F[[x]]$ endowed with its standard topology is a topological vector space over the topological field $(F, discrete)$, and the monomials are a Schauder basis for this topological vector space.

Comment: To summarize, you want a new topology on $F[[x]]$ for which addition and scalar multiplication are still continuous, and $(x)_n$ is a Schauder basis. You are not requiring power series multiplication to be continuous, correct? If not, I have an answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Never mind, what I thought would work did not. Interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the question.

With the axiom of choice there is some $F$-vector subspace such that $$F[[x]]=W\oplus F[x]$$

For a sequence $c_n\in F$ we get the unique decomposition $$\sum_{n\ge 0}c_n x^n= w(c)+\sum_{k=0}^{d(c)} a_k(c) x^k$$

When $c_n$ is zero for $n> N$ we have $w(c)=0$ thus $d(c)=N$,$a_k(c)=c_k$.

Sending $c_n$ to $$w(c)+\sum_{k=0}^{d(c)} a_k(c) (x)_k$$
gives an alternative topology on $F[[x]]$, the topology inherited from that of $F^\Bbb{N}$.

By definition of the alternative topology $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N c_n (x)_n =w(c)+\sum_{k=0}^{d(c)} a_k(c) (x)_k$$

Comment: Even if you don't see the point of the question, it might be useful to state whether you are arguing that answer is obviously yes, obviously no, or that the question makes no sense, or whatever other conclusion you came to.